# Model from a different project in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to spring mvc and I'm trying to add a model I created in a different project from my web project(where I keep the configuration and the controllers).

When I say "use" this models I mean as a return value or as an input parameter from one of my controller's methods. If I use those models as a variable inside of the methods there is no problem.

The web project compiles and everything is good but when I restart Tomcat I see in the logs that he doesn't recognize the models from the other project(if they are in the web project then it's all good).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... All I needed to do it to add the external project to the web's Deployment Assembly and not only to the Java Build Path.

Thanks!